# How to use a field value on elemMatch in aggregation?

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection of plans with an array of recipes. I'm trying to filter recipes that were planned in a specific meal, but I'm struggling to make the $match step work with the name of the recipe of the current document.

Working example:

```json
[{$match: {
  nome: "Banana"
}}, {$lookup: {
  from: 'planejamentos',
  localField: '_id',
  foreignField: 'receitas._id',
  as: 'planejamentos'
}}, {$match: {

    "planejamentos.receitas": {
    $elemMatch : {
      nome: "Banana",
      refeicao:  "Café da Manhã"
    }
  }
}}]
```

But I'd like to make the last $match step using the name of the recipe like this:

```json
[{$match: {
  nome: "Banana"
}}, {$lookup: {
  from: 'planejamentos',
  localField: '_id',
  foreignField: 'receitas._id',
  as: 'planejamentos'
}}, {$match: {

    "planejamentos.receitas": {
    $elemMatch : {
      nome: "$nome",
      refeicao:  "Café da Manhã"
    }
  }
}}]
```

But the `nome: "$nome"` does not evaluate the name and the result is 0 documents

How to combine `$elemMatch` with `$[field-name]` or `$lookup` pipeline with `$elemMatch` or any workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not satisfied but I've solved by unwinding the arrays.

```json
[{$match: {
  nome: "Banana"
}}, {$lookup: {
  from: 'planejamentos',
  localField: '_id',
  foreignField: 'receitas._id',
  as: 'planejamentos'
}}, {$unwind: {
  path: "$planejamentos",
  includeArrayIndex: 'posicaoPlanejamento',
  preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: false
}}, {$unwind: {
  path: "$planejamentos.receitas",
  includeArrayIndex: 'posicaoReceita',
  preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: false
}}, {$match: {
  $expr: {
    $and: [
      {$eq: ["$planejamentos.receitas.nome", "$nome"]}, 
      {$eq: ["$planejamentos.receitas.refeicao","Café da Manhã"]}
      ]
  }
}}, {}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can't add a path in the $match, you should add that match conditions to your lookup pipeline.

Something like this:

```
{
    $lookup: {
        from: 'planejamentos',
        'let': {
            nome: "$nome",
            _id: '$_id',
        },
        pipeline: [
            {
                $match: {
                    $and: [
                        {
                            $expr: {
                                $eq: [
                                    '$nome',
                                    '$$nome'
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            $expr: {
                                $eq: [
                                    '$$_id',
                                    '$receitas._id'
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            $expr: {
                                $eq: [
                                    '"Café da Manhã"',
                                    '$refeicao'
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        as: 'planejamentos'
    }
}
```

It also would help if you post some examples of your data.

Comment: Didn't work because it's an array of recipes.

Comment: Could you post some examples of your data? @RobertoOSantos